# CSS add margin to one element in menu

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering how to add a `left-margin` to the most right element in
the menu without changing HTML code.

MY CODE:

```css
ul {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 115px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

ul li a.li-login {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  border: none;
}
ul li:nth-child(5){
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="main">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
      
      <li><a href="/projects/endlessblow">EndlessBlow</a></li>
      
      <li><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6173561253714763017">My projects</a></li>
      
      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
      
      <li *ngIf="!isLogged"><input type="submit" class="a-login" value="Login" (click)="navigateToLogin()"></li>
      
      <li *ngIf="isLogged"><input type="submit" class="a-login" value="Logout" (click)="doLogout()"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

what the output I have:

[image]

but I need to add `margin` to have space like in the image below:

[image]

How can I achieve that with CSS?

Comment: ul li:nth-child(4) a {
 margin-right:50px;
}

Comment: Why are you using all this !importent?
Its wrong to use !Importent in this case.
beside,i suggest you to learn about Flex containers,which will make your life much easier,if you want i can show you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the pseudo-class called `nth-child(n)`, with this class you can select a child element based on the number `n`, in the code below you select the five `li` element which is a child and add a margin to it, now you can add styles only to the 5 `li` element.

```css
ul {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 115px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

ul li a.li-login {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  border: none;
}
ul li:nth-child(5){
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="main">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
      
      <li><a href="/projects/endlessblow">EndlessBlow</a></li>
      
      <li><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6173561253714763017">My projects</a></li>
      
      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
      
      <li *ngIf="!isLogged"><input type="submit" class="a-login" value="Login" (click)="navigateToLogin()"></li>
      
      <li *ngIf="isLogged"><input type="submit" class="a-login" value="Logout" (click)="doLogout()"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
width:100%;
text-align: center;
```

in your `ul` and

```
.a-login {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```css
.a-login {
margin-left: 50px;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 115px;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

ul li a.li-login {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/projects/endlessblow">EndlessBlow</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6173561253714763017">My projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
      <li *ngIf="!isLogged"><input type="submit" class="a-login" value="Login" (click)="navigateToLogin()"></li>
      <li *ngIf="isLogged"><input type="submit" class="a-login" value="Logout" (click)="doLogout()"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Run your code snippet and look at the image he posted, he wants the buttons away from the actual links.

Comment: @TudorAlexandru Sorry you're right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

you've many options but my choice would be number 1:

1

```
ul li:last-child {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

2

```
ul li:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

3

```
ul li a[href="/about"] {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

4

```
ul li:nth-child(4) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

5

```
ul li:nth-child(5) {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```